# Is there a reducing function in Clojure that performs the equivalent of `first`?

Tags: clojure, mapreduce, transducer

I'm often writing code of the form

```
(->> init
     (map ...)
     (filter ...)
     (first))
```

When converting this into code that uses transducers I'll end up with something like

```
(transduce (comp (map ...) (filter ...)) (completing #(reduced %2)) nil init)
```

Writing `(completing #(reduced %2))` instead of `first` doesn't sit well with me at all. It needlessly obscures a very straightforward task. Is there a more idiomatic way of performing this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally use your approach with a custom reducing function but here are some alternatives:

```
(let [[x] (into [] (comp (map inc) (filter even?) (take 1)) [0 1])]
    x)
```

Using destructing :/

Or:

```
(first (eduction (map inc) (filter even?) [0 1])
```

Here you save on calling `comp` which is done for you. Though it's not super lazy. It'll realize up to 32 elements so it's potentially wasteful.
Fixed with a `(take 1)`:

```
(first (eduction (map inc) (filter even?) (take 1) [0 1]))
```

Overall a bit shorter and not too unclear compared to:

```
(transduce (comp (map inc) (filter even?) (take 1)) (completing #(reduced %2)) nil [0 1])
```

If you need this a bunch, then I'd probably *NOT* create a custom reducer function but instead a function similar to transduce that takes `xform, coll` as the argument and returns the first value. It's clearer what it does and you can give it a nice docstring. If you want to save on calling `comp` you can also make it similar to `eduction`:

```
(defn single-xf
  "Returns the first item of transducing the xforms over collection"
  {:arglists '([xform* coll])}
  [& xforms]
  (transduce (apply comp (butlast xforms)) (completing #(reduced %2)) nil (last xforms)))
```

Example:

```
(single-xf (map inc) (filter even?) [0 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

[medley](https://github.com/weavejester/medley) has `find-first` with a transducer arity and [xforms](https://github.com/cgrand/xforms) has a reducing function called `last`. I think that the combination of the two is what you're after.

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:require
   [medley.core :as medley]
   [net.cgrand.xforms.rfs :as rfs]))

(transduce (comp (map ,,,) (medley/find-first ,,,)) rfs/last init)
```

Comment: Two additional dependencies is a rather steep price. At that point I might as well do `(def first-reduce (completing #(reduced %2)))` myself. The problem with these kinds of approaches is that, if applied consistently, they gradually turn my code into a special dialect of Clojure that only I myself will be able to penetrate.